# Conditional probability textbook question

Tags: conditional-probability

I'm just looking for a confirmation. Textbook answer for this problem is $\frac{1}{18}$ but I'm getting $\frac{1}{20}$...

You have 7 tickets to a baseball game. Three tickets are in the left field stands, 2 are behind home plate and 2 are near first base. Two tickets are randomly given to your sister. You notice that one of the tickets is not behind home plate. Calculate the probability that both tickets are near first base.

$P(A|B)=\cfrac{\frac{1}{21}}{\frac{20}{21}}=\cfrac{1}{20}$

Am I missing something? Is there a faster way to solve these problems than doing a probability tree or listing the possible outcomes?

Comment: Is your assumption that *exactly one* or *at least one* of the two tickets is not near Home?

Comment: @lulu the way I see it, we only know that one is not near home, we can't assume anything about the other...?

Comment: So, it's *at least one* then?  The probability that at least one is not near home is $1-\frac 1{21}=\frac {20}{21}$.  The probability that both are near first is $\frac 1{21}$, so I agree with your calculation.

Comment: Note:  there are $10$ combinations with *exactly* one not near home, making the probability of that $\frac {10}{21}$.  The numerator is unchanged, making the answer $\frac 1{10}$ in that case.  No guess where the $\frac 1{18}$ came from.

Comment: @lulu Thanks for your help! I notice that if the condition was *one of the tickets is not in the stands*, the answer would be $\frac{1}{18}$... it's the only thing I can see...

Comment: Oh, good catch.  That seems as likely as anything.